# TypeScript optional generic in type

Tags: typescript

I'm curious could I make this generic optional somehow?

```
export type RequestType<T> = {
  readonly type: string;
  readonly value: string | T;
};
```

Because when I try to set object' type to `RequestType` it returns an error, that generic type requires 1 type argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a default type for T. For example:

```
export type RequestType<T = boolean> = {
  readonly type: string;
  readonly value: string | T;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBKwCOBXYBnGAFWWAB5C4BeOAIwggBtgBDAOwD4q4BvAWACg4cKCwAmEVg0QISALjgEoAS1YBzANwChI5uMnSAbswa55ilargAfOIU38AvgIEBjCQTihmAWzBMAjPIYOPhEJFx8gjIo8gDkAGb0sQA0WnBGJsDyMFC4qY7O-G6sHl6%20TABMQVi4BMQopKzY3jTAUJzUkUJIMXAJSflCGaZwAMz5DkA)

The default value can even be `string` if you like, and thus `value` will be `string | string`, also known as just `string`.

Comment: I could, but I don't want to. I want it to remain `string | T` or just `string`.

Comment: @Cholewka You can set the default type to `never` to get that behavior.

Comment: `or just string` Then default it to `string` or `never`

Comment: Thank you, that's what I've been looking for :)